# how to check if the files exist on remote server or not

Tags: 14.04, bash, scripts, ssh

I need to check on Linux Remote server if the files exists in folder or not and according to result need to perform some action.

thats how my script looks like.

```
 #/bin/bash

HOST=upload@IP
DIR=/var/www/Upload/MC/mxf/
FILE='20200821-012*'

find "$DIR" -maxdepth 1 -name "$FILE"

if [[ $(ssh "$HOST" find "$DIR" -maxdepth 1 -name "$FILE" ) != "" ... ]];

then

   echo "The file exists"

else

  echo "The file doesn't exist."

fi
```

I am getting this Error when I run the script

```
    user@svv-at001:~# sh -x /scripts/ch.sh 
+ HOST=upload@IP
+ DIR=/var/www/Upload/MC/mxf/
+ FILE=20200821-012*
+ find /var/www/Upload/MC/mxf/ -maxdepth 1 -name 20200821-012*
find: ‘/var/www/Upload/MC/mxf/’: No such file or directory
+ ssh upload@IP find /var/www/Upload/MC/mxf/ -maxdepth 1 -name 20200821-012*
+ [[ /var/www/Upload/MC/mxf/20200821-012_007.mxf /var/www/Upload/MC/mxf/20200821-012_012.mxf /var/www/Upload/MC/mxf/20200821-012_010.mxf /var/www/Upload/MC/mxf/20200821-012_001.mxf /var/www/Upload/MC/mxf/20200821-012_005.mxf /var/www/Upload/MC/mxf/20200821-012_008.mxf  !=  ... ]]
/scripts/ch.sh: 13: /scripts/ch.sh: [[: not found
+ echo The file doesn't exist.
The file doesn't exist.
```

any tip will be appreciated.

thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the variables with single quotes to avoid expansion of the wild-card in your local computer,

```
FILE='20200819-001-*'
```

The command `find` can manage wild-cards, so I suggest the following command instead of the simple test,

```
find "$DIR" -maxdepth 1 -name "$FILE"
```

or if you want to check in subdirectories without limiting the depth of the search,

```
find "$DIR" -name "$FILE"
```

So in your shellscript you check if the `find` command line produces some output or not,

```
if [[ $(ssh "$HOST" find "$DIR" -maxdepth 1 -name "$FILE" ) != "" ]]
```

Comment: `if [[ $(ssh "$HOST" find "$DIR" -maxdepth 1 -name "$FILE" ) != "" ]]

then

   echo "The file exists"

else

 #  echo "The file doesn't exist."

fi

Comment: it gives me error, or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Try with `... ]]; then echo "..."; else echo "..." ; fi` that is remove the '#` and add a semicolon before then before else and before fi.

Comment: Did you set HOST, DIR and FILE in your shellscript?

Comment: find: ‘/var/www/Upload/MC/mxf/’: No such file or directory
/scripts/ch.sh: 13: /scripts/ch.sh: [[: not found
The file doesn't exist.

thats the out of the script

Comment: Please edit your original question to show the current version of your shellscript. (It is very difficult, almost impossible, to understand what you say in a comment because newlines and converted to spaces. so I don't know what is a space and what is a newline.)

Comment: Updated the question with current script and error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112390/discussion-between-sudodus-and-kunal).

Answer (score 0):

Its simple

```
if [[ "`ssh -q hostname ls /dir/filename.abc 2>dev/null`" == "/dir/filename.abc" ]]
then
echo "file exists"
else
echo "file not exists"
fi
```